# Sorting a List<T> using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, sorting

```
List<DatsWussup.Models.Message> messages = mc.GetMessages();
List<DatsWussup.Models.JQGridMessage> gridMessages = FormatMessages(messages);

int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
int pageSize = rows;
int totalRecords = gridMessages.Count;
int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

var questions = gridMessages
    .OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord)
    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize);
```

So I am following along with the JqGrid and MVC guide here : http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx and in the step where he adds sorting/paging, I took the above code from the blog.

Now, you can probably see what I am trying to do just from looking at the code, especially if you are familiar with working with JqGrids and MVC together. However, I'm getting this error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

When I try to compile the above code. I'm not very good with LINQ or any delegates in general, could I get a little help?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the types of `sidx` and `sord` and where are they declared?

Comment: They are both strings and they are sent as parameters to the function that this code is in from the front end. This code is in a controller function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrderBy()` takes either a `Func<TSource, TKey>` delegate, an expression `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>` or if you have DLINQ, a string.  The blog mentions that you need DLINQ and links to the [download page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) and [ScottGu's article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).  Apparently you don't have it.

Download it, add `LinqSamples\DynamicQuery\DynamicQuery\Dynamic.cs` to your project and use the `System.Linq.Dynamic` namespace and it should be made available to you.

Answer (score 0):

`OrderBy` is expecting a lambda expression, maybe something like this:

```
var questions = gridMessages
    .OrderBy(m => m.sidx + " " + m.sord)
    .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: sidx and sord are properties passed to me by the jqgrid on the front end. sidx is the column name to sort by, and sord is the sort type (asc or desc). The model doesn't have these as properties, so that won't work =/

Comment: Then you can't do it like that anyway, you need to build an expression dynamically then.

Comment: How does the man do it in his example in that blog linked in my post?

Comment: @Scott: As stated in that post, he used [Dynamic Linq Query library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) that allows to build LINQ query based on strings.